# Passing the table as a parameter

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.3

I have to convert from lat and long to `geom` to use PostGIS. My problem, I have various tables from different locations and I want to pass the table as a parameter to the function. I'm trying this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION convert_from_lon_lat(float,float,character varying)      
RETURNS  integer AS $$
select id from $3 as vertices 
order by  vertices.geom <-> ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint($1,$2),4326) LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

but I get a syntax error.

EDIT1:

So I changed the previous code to this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION convert_from_lon_lat(long float, lat float, _table character varying) RETURNS  integer AS $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE('select id from _table as vertices order by  vertices.geom <-> ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(long,lat),4326) LIMIT 1;');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

it creates without any problem, but when I call it `convert_from_lon_lat(long1, long2, my_table)

I get and error:

```
ERROR:  relation "_table" does not exist
```

It's not passing the table name as an argument

EDIT 2:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION convert_from_lon_lat(long float, lat float, tbl character varying) RETURNS  integer AS $func$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('select id from %s order by  %s.the_geom <-> ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint('|| long || ','|| lat ||'),4326) LIMIT 1;', tbl, tbl);
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now when I call the function, I get an `ERROR:  control reached end of function without RETURN``

I tried `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('...` but I get a `ERROR:  cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function`

Comment: You might have to use PL/pgSQL and a dynamic SQL construct.

Comment: I very n00b in postgres, how I'd do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS @dezso mentioned, you'll need dynamic SQL in this case.

## Dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`

So, you're on the right track;  forming a dynamic SQL statement using PL/pgSQL, but you just need the finishing touches:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION convert_from_lon_lat(long float, lat float, _table text) 
RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT id FROM %I AS vertices 
  ORDER BY vertices.geom <->ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(long,lat),4326) LIMIT 1;',_table);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I believe this should solve your issues.

Note:  We've discovered an error with the above solution and using `SETOF`, I've attempted to correct the issues below.

## EDIT:

A few edits here, hopefully one solution will fix your issue. Also, please excuse any syntax errors in my previous & current solutions; I don't have time to test them right now. :(

**1)**  You could just try returning a `SETOF` integers, knowing that of course you'll only return the one.  Your return type in this case will then be a single, one-column row containing an integer.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION convert_from_lon_lat(long float, lat float, _table text) 
RETURNS SETOF integer AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT id FROM %I AS vertices 
  ORDER BY vertices.geom <->ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(long,lat),4326) LIMIT 1;',_table);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and then call as:

```
SELECT * FROM convert_from_lon_lat(...);
```

**2)**  To specifically return an integer, I think you can try this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION convert_from_lon_lat(long float, lat float, _table text) 
RETURNS integer AS $$

DECLARE
return_id integer;

BEGIN
EXECUTE format('SELECT id FROM %I AS vertices 
  ORDER BY vertices.geom <->ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(long,lat),4326) LIMIT 1;',_table)
  INTO return_id;

RETURN return_id;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I updated the question, I tried that solution and I got a `ERROR:  cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function`

Comment: So, there are two possible solutions to this.  I'll try to see if I can make the appropriate edits...